# I am facing issue in hiding the cell from gridview in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

We have tried the below code.

```
DataGrid ObjDataGrid = (DataGrid)this.FindName("TileGrid");

DataGridCellInfo ob = new DataGridCellInfo(ObjDataGrid.CurrentCell, ObjDataGrid.CurrentCell.Column);

var obj = ob.Column.GetCellContent(ObjDataGrid.CurrentCell.Item);
obj.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
```

But in this we get the cell information when we click on the particular cell.
I want to hide the cell while loading the cells in grid view without clicking on the cell.
Can anyone help in this.

Comment: Whatever language this is, you should add it as a tag.

Comment: @Akshay where are performing the activity in any event ?

Comment: In your Constructor created the following: `this.TileGrid.LoadingRow += (s,e)=> {};` and insert the above code inside the `{ }`